# ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element sizeの解決方法

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

#### 前提・実現したいこと

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

というエラーメッセージの解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

以下のプログラムは

任意のSignal-to-Noise比の音声波形をPythonで作ろう！
https://engineering.linecorp.com/ja/blog/voice-waveform-arbitrary-signal-to-noise-ratio-python/

音声処理　TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
https://teratail.com/questions/306716
の質問などを参考にしています。

手順として、
https://github.com/Sato-Kunihiko/audio-SNR#usage
こちらのreadmeを参考に

pip install pipenv
↓
pipenv install
↓
pipenv shell

をした後に
create_mixed_audio_file.py
を実行しています。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-d5415e64c65c> in <module>
     46 
     47     clean_amp = cal_amp(clean_wav)
---> 48     noise_amp = cal_amp(noise_wav)
     49 
     50     start = random.randint(0, len(noise_amp)-len(clean_amp))

<ipython-input-50-d5415e64c65c> in cal_amp(wf)
     27 def cal_amp(wf):
     28     buffer = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
---> 29     amptitude = (np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype="int16")).astype(np.float64)
     30     return amptitude
     31 

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import argparse
import array
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import wave


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--clean_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--noise_file', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--output_clean_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noise_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noisy_file', type=str, default='', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--snr', type=float, default='', required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args(args=['--clean_file',"sample.wav", '--noise_file', "noise.wav", '--output_clean_file',"clear.wav",'--output_noise_file',"noise.wav",'--output_noisy_file',"noisy.wav",'--snr',0])
    return args


def cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms, snr):
    a = float(snr) / 20
    noise_rms = clean_rms / (10**a) 
    return noise_rms


def cal_amp(wf):
    buffer = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
    amptitude = (np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype="int16")).astype(np.float64)
    return amptitude


def cal_rms(amp):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(amp), axis=-1))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    args = get_args()
    clean_file = args.clean_file
    noise_file = args.noise_file
    snr = args.snr

    clean_wav = wave.open(clean_file, "r")
    noise_wav = wave.open(noise_file, "r")

    clean_amp = cal_amp(clean_wav)
    noise_amp = cal_amp(noise_wav)

    start = random.randint(0, len(noise_amp)-len(clean_amp))
    clean_rms = cal_rms(clean_amp)
    split_noise_amp = noise_amp[start: start + len(clean_amp)]
    noise_rms = cal_rms(split_noise_amp)

    adjusted_noise_rms = cal_adjusted_rms(clean_rms, snr)

    adjusted_noise_amp = split_noise_amp * (adjusted_noise_rms / noise_rms) 
    mixed_amp = (clean_amp + adjusted_noise_amp)


    if (mixed_amp.max(axis=0) > 32767): 
        mixed_amp = mixed_amp * (32767/mixed_amp.max(axis=0))
        clean_amp = clean_amp * (32767/mixed_amp.max(axis=0))
        adjusted_noise_amp = adjusted_noise_amp * (32767/mixed_amp.max(axis=0))


    noisy_wave = wave.Wave_write(args.output_noisy_file)
    noisy_wave.setparams(clean_wav.getparams())
    noisy_wave.writeframes(array.array('h', mixed_amp.astype(np.int16)).tostring() )
    noisy_wave.close()


    clean_wave = wave.Wave_write(args.output_clean_file)
    clean_wave.setparams(clean_wav.getparams())
    clean_wave.writeframes(array.array('h', clean_amp.astype(np.int16)).tostring() )
    clean_wave.close()


    noise_wave = wave.Wave_write(args.output_noise_file)
    noise_wave.setparams(clean_wav.getparams())
    noise_wave.writeframes(array.array('h', adjusted_noise_amp.astype(np.int16)).tostring() )
    noise_wave.close()
```

Comment: 指定した`noise.wav`ファイルのデータ形式問題では？ `get_args()`内に決め打ちで指定している`sample.wav`と`noise.wav`のファイルを、動作した実績のあるGitHubリポジトリの`data/16_bit`配下のファイルに置き換えて試してみてはどうでしょう？ こんな記事 [ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58733168/9014308) が参考になるかもしれませんし、またGitHubのreadmeには`Can read wav file with 16-bit PCM only`と書いてあります。あるいは`--noise_file`と`--output_noise_file`に同じ`noise.wav`が指定されているので、複数回実行すると2回目以降は形式が合わなくなるとかありませんか？

Comment: 言われた通り、使用されていたノイズファイルで実行したらうまくいきました。create_mixed_audio_file_with_soundfile.pyでも同じ動作ができました。また、--noise_fileが重複している件ですが、こちらも特に不具合はありません。連続して実行しても正常に動きます。